# Is there a way to show data from a database in node.js via a html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, database

I am fairly new to coding and I encountered something I couldn't solve nor find on google.

this is my code:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

const {
Pool,
Client
} = require("pg");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //__dir and not _dir
let port = 2000; // you can use any port
app.listen(port);
console.log('serving files on' + ' ' + port);

const pool = new Pool({
user: 'postgres',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'myFirstDb',
password: '.....',
port: 3010,
max: 20,
connectionTimeoutMillis: 0,
idleTimeoutMillis: 0
})

let results = {};

app.get("/all", async (req, res) => {
const fromDate = new Date();

//return all rows

results = await pool.query("select name, income, spendings from income")
// console.table(results.rows)

// this line here doesn't work because I found out you could not use variables like this because 
// node does not have a DOM element.
document.getElementById('yep').innerHTML = results

console.log(new Date())
const toDate = new Date();
const elapsed = toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime();

//send it to the wire
res.send({
    rows: results.rows,
    elapsed: elapsed,
    method: "pool"
})

const timestamps = await pool.query('insert into timestamps values ($1)', [fromDate])

})

app.listen(2015, () => console.log("Listening on port 2015"))



// SECOND PART //




const client = new Client({
user: 'postgres',
host: 'localhost',
database: 'myFirstDb',
password: 'tenCores10',
port: 3010,
})

async function insert() {
// things that should happen
try {
    // wait till this is finished before doing anything else
    await client.connect()
    // then...
    console.log('Connected succesfully')
    const inserting = await client.query('insert into income values ($1, $2, $3)', [8, 1, 'jay'])
    // deleting it right away, just to keep it working
    const deleting = await client.query('delete from income where income = 8')
    const results = await client.query('select * from income')
    console.table(results.rows)
    //send it to the wire


    // catching errors
} catch (error) {
    console.log(`That went wrong ${error}`)

} // finish it 
finally {
    await client.end()
    console.log('client disconnected succesfully')
}
}
insert();
```

I am writing a node.js file called 'pool.js'. I have two different connections in there, one on localhost:2000 and the other on localhost:2015/all. the first one is with a client and the second one is with a pool.

The thing is that I would like to show the results I get from my postgres database with a html file on the localhost. But I can't seem to get the constant 'results' in a way to a html file. If I now check localhost:2015/all it does show the database data but it's all cropped up and I can't adjust it how it is located in the page.

So my question is: Is there a way how I could get the database data displayed on a webpage via a html file?

This is how my folder looks like:

[image: folder in visual studio code]

I hope I added enough info, but if I am missing something please let me know. And sorry for the code which looks a bit messed up, but I can't seem to get the spaces in the code sample right.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You could use template view engines with express like [ejs](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express) or [pug](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

Comment: @Wazeed. thanks! I will look into that.